# Lazy Loading For Mobile Optimization

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, lazy-loading

Below is the code that I'm using on my website. It runs well over wi-fi, but the website often freezes and crashes when testing it out over a mobile network. One of the issues for this is that (I believe) all the content on the page loads at once and is difficult to load on a mobile device.

I've tried several different techniques to try and get the photos on my website to lazy load so that it could run more efficiently, but nothing seems to be working. If anyone knows how I could go about doing this it'd be much appreciated if you could share your knowledge with me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
    
<body>
    
<style>html{visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;}</style>
    
<title>MORIKOBOSHI・</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">About This Website</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Bibliography</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;">
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Custom Google Search" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;">
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style="padding-left: 5px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 50px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;">
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html">    

</form>
</div>    

    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:morikoboshi.com' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
 
</script>


<script>
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
} 
 
if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    window.location.reload();
}
</script>

</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
    
 <br><br><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">◯◯◯◯</h1>
    <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;"></p>
    
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Author: ◯◯◯◯</p>
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Photos/Videos Taken：◯◯◯◯/◯◯/◯◯</p>
    
 <br><br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;">    
    
    #
 </p>    
        
</div>
        
<br><br><div class="image">
    
  <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">MORIKOBOSHI© | <a href="#">日本語</a></footer>

</div>
</div>
      
<style>
    
html {visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;}
    
.body{background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;}
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 20px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be loading any scripts and there isn't much markup or CSS. In what way is it failing to load?

Comment: After viewing several of the web pages on a mobile device none of the links will be accessible, and when scrolling up and down on the screen content will disappear and I'm left with a blank white space.

Comment: You are probably in an infinite loop. Can you add a debug statement in the if statement where you reload the page with `window.location.reload();`? Also, why are you reloading at all?

Comment: Originally, I was trying to get the menu bar to close (when using it on a mobile device) when returning to a previously viewed page. I didn't know how to achieve this so I went with using this script.